# When to use a payable function vs. a receive function

Tags: solidity, payable, receive

This SO answer explains the differences between using a function marked with `payable` versus the contract implementing a `receive` function and then sending ETH directly to the contract: [why contract must have a receive()/fallback() to receive ether? isn't a payable function enough？](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/125337/why-contract-must-have-a-receive-fallback-to-receive-ether-isnt-a-payable)

My question is: *when* does it make more sense to use a function marked `payable` versus simply having a `receive` function? Both solve the same problem of allowing your contract to receive ETH, but I do not know what scenarios would favor implementing one over the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct that both approaches accomplish the same goal of letting your contract increase its ETH balance. One is better than the other depending on the type of API you want users of your contract to have.

Below I'll explain where the `receive` function is best used, and where having a `payable` function is best.

tldr: The difference depends on whether the address interacting with your contract knows how your contract works (i.e. what public functions your contract exposes).

**`receive` function:**

In scenarios where you want a user to be able to send ETH to your contract, without any knowledge of how your contract works, a `receive` function is the way to go. The best example of this is a smart contract wallet like [Gnosis Safe Wallet](https://gnosis-safe.io/). If Alice wants to send funds to Bob's Safe Wallet which implement `receive`, all she has to do is call `payable(bobs_safe_address).call{value: amount}("")`. No matter what Gnosis does internally, Alice can easily send her funds to Bob in a single transaction and with no knowledge of the contract's internal workings.

If the Gnosis contract had a `payable` function instead of `receive`, then Alice would need to lookup what the function name and what its arguments are (if any), and then call that function while passing in the amount of ETH value she wants to send. This is more complicated than simply sending ETH in to the contract, and the simplicity of the `receive` is why it's preferred here.

**`payable` function:**

When your contract has a function that requires some non-zero ETH value in order to function correctly, this is where you should favor a `payable` function over a simple `receive` function.

An example of this would be if you were building a `Charity` contract, which exposes a `function contribute() public payable` function. Alice already knows about the functions exposed by the `Charity` contract, and knows she needs to call `Charity.contribute` in order to have her contribution correctly recorded by the contract. In this case marking the address as `payable` is the way to go. If the contract had the `contribute` function **AND** the `receive` function, or just a `receive` function that internally executed the `contribute` function, this would be a more confusing API because it's less clear to Alice what she needs to do in order to get her contribution correctly recorded.

The most ambiguous situation to decide between the two is when there is only one function that needs to be marked `payable` on your contract, and you're trying to decide whether to implement that function's logic as its owned named function (e.g. `contribute`) or to just use a `receive` function. In that case I think it's still best to use a named `contribute` function marked `payable`, because then you prevent users from unknowingly sending ETH to your contract when they didn't mean to.